# Wrangling x-axis datetime labels on matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas DataFrame with a DateTime index.

I can plot a timeseries from it, and by default it looks fine.

But when I try to print a bar chart from the same DataFrame,  the xAxis labels are ruined (massive overlapping). (Also the spacing of the data is weird (big gaps between sets of bars)

I tried `autoformat_xdate()`, but that didn't help anything.

[image]

This is the simple code fragment I used to generate the charts

```
entire_df['predict'] = regr.predict(entire_df[X_cols])
entire_df['error'] = entire_df['predict']-entire_df['px_usd_mmbtu']
#entire_df['error'].plot(kind='hist')
fig=plt.figure()
entire_df[['px_usd_mmbtu', 'predict']].plot()
fig2 = plt.figure()
entire_df['error'].plot(kind='bar')
#fig2.autofmt_xdate()              #doesn't help
print (type(error_df.index))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
entire_df['predict'] = regr.predict(entire_df[X_cols])
entire_df['error'] = entire_df['predict']-entire_df['px_usd_mmbtu']

plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
plt.xticks(rotation = 90) # or change from 90 to 45

#entire_df['error'].plot(kind='hist')

entire_df[['px_usd_mmbtu', 'predict']].plot()
entire_df['error'].plot(kind='bar')
```